# How can i pass event information between components on Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have been tasked with building an online food ordering system using Vue.js.

As you can see on my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek0873m6/7/), I have a list of **menu sections** displayed at the top of the page.

What I am looking to do is the following: when a **menu section** is clicked, I want to do an `ajax` request and get the full section information and pass it to the `menu-section-info` component.

I then also want to be able to know if the user has clicked **Add to favourites** and pass this to an `ajax` request.

I know how to make `ajax` requests, but I am unfamiliar with events in `vue.js` and how to use these to pass information between components.

It looks like i can add the 'v-on:click' attribute to the menu-section component or on the li item within this.  Would this be the correct approach to take? and how would i pass the clicked menu-section details into the menu-section-info component?

Thanks in advance

```
Vue.component('menu-section', {
    props: ['menusection'],
    template: '<li>{{ menusection.name }}</li>'
})

Vue.component('menu-section-info', {
    props: ['menusectioninfo'],
    template: '#menusectioninfo-template'
})

new Vue({
        el:'#app',
    data: {
            // this will be retrieved using an ajax request
        menuSectionList: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Pizzas' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Burgers' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Wraps' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Drinks' },
            { id: 5, name: 'Sweets' }
        ]
    }
})

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
        <ol>
            <menu-section v-for="item in menuSectionList"
                        v-bind:menusection="item"
                        v-bind:key="item.id">
            </menu-section>
        </ol>

        <div style="margin-top:20px;">
         <!-- The info here has been hardcoded, it should be retrieved using an ajax request when one of the sections has been clicked. The favourites link should also make and ajax request passing the selected section. -->
          <menu-section-info menusectioninfo="We sell the best burgers in the world!"></menu-section-info>
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="menusectioninfo-template">
  <div>
    <div>{{ menusectioninfo }}</div>
    <div><a href="#">Click here to add section to your favourites list</a></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: You should start with [vue router](http://jsfiddle.net/posva/wtpuevc6/) and read about [fetching data](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Since this is a practice exercise for me, i don't want to use routers at the moment.  This is specifically about updating other components when there has been an event.

Comment: See [Passing Data To Child Components with Props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and [Sending Messages to Parents with Events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events)